# Converting Solr query spatial search syntax to Lucene

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have the below Solr query and I am looking for equivalent Lucene query syntax:

```
"&fl=*,score,distance:{!func}geodist(latLong,41.188222,-73.19544)
```

Comment: May we see a start on your Lucene query, Jess, edited into the question? That will help readers understand where _in particular_ you are getting stuck.

Comment: so, what's your problem? what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that is not a query.
When rendering the results in Solr you are rendering the resulting documents, calculating for each doc an additional field ( distance).
This is called Function values as pseudo-fields[1]
This field is calculated, fetching the stored content from each resulting document and applying a function query to calculate the distance from a point.

To do this in Lucene you need to explore the concept of ValueSource[2].
Bare in mind that from a quick look the ValueSource for geo distance is actually Solr side[3].
So you may need to import it potentially.

[1] https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-FunctionValues

[2] org.apache.lucene.queries.function.valuesource, org.apache.lucene.queries.function.TestValueSources

[3] org.apache.solr.schema.LatLonValueSource

Comment: Thanks for the update My basic question is is there a syntax for lucene query for spatial search?

Comment: There is an entire package for spatial search in Lucene : org.apache.lucene.spatial.query

Remember Lucene is just a library , so you need to build queries on your own or use a query parsers.

For examples just refer to the search() method in this class :
org.apache.lucene.spatial.SpatialExample